# is there a way to change directory as a different user?

Tags: powershell, cd

In order for the whole script to work, it needs to be run as the logged on user, however I have to change the directory to a folder that requires elevated credentials to open.

> > **cd "C:\privatefolder\application"**
> > .\program.vsto -credential $credential

When it comes to running the install I'm able to do -credential to run it as elevated, but it looks like change directory doesn't have the same options.

I'm a powershell novice since my job is mainly hardware support so you may have to explain it like I'm a caveman.

Comment: You can invoke scriptblocks as a different user, see https://gist.github.com/jborean93/3c148df03545023c671ddefb2d2b5ffc

Comment: That function looks promising, @SantiagoSquarzon, but on my W11 machine I cannot get it to execute any external program from the impersonating script block (whether directly or with `Start-Process -Credential`, as recommended): always get `Access denied`, even when running with elevation to begin with (`-LogonType Interactive`). Does it work for you? `Invoke-WithImpersonation { whoami.exe }`

Comment: It sounds like your best bet is to run your commands in an elevated session, along the lines of: `Start-Process -Wait -Verb RunAs -WorkingDirectory C:\privatefolder\application  .\program.vsto`. `-Verb RunAs` requests elevation and triggers a UAC prompt; note that you cannot use specific credentials. If that doesn't help, please [edit] your question to clarify your requirements.

Comment: @mklement0 `Invoke-WithImpersonation -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { [System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent().Name }.GetNewClosure()` works fine for me using `whoami` gets me access denied. had asked the author to see why could it be

Comment: @mklement0 The impersonation only works for things that run in the same thread, it doesn't work for external applications but would have access to anything the powershell process has access to (basically all .NET)

Comment: Thanks, @SantiagoSquarzon, I went by the comment-based help, which I read to mean that you _can_ invoke external programs - albeit with direct invocation _without_ impersonation - and via `Start-Process -Credential` _with_ impersonation - but neither works. I suppose the latter refers to using `Start-Process -Credential` _without_ `Invoke-WithImpersonation`